# Excel / Automatically move complete row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to edit a excel spreadsheet so that a row automatically moves from one sheet ("Open_Followups") to another sheet ("Closed_Followups") if it contains "Yes" in column "I" ("Event completed/closed").

I have no experience in VBA and was wondering if someone here could help me creating the code?

Screenshot of the first columns in on the sheet.

[image: screenshot]

Not sure if it is important but I am using Excel 2016 on a Mac computer

Comment: Don't ask for code here, you should provide a minimum of research

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script for you (in MS Excel) that searches for a "y" in row B and if it finds a match it copies the value from row A to the Sheet "Tabelle2".
This is just an example (I'm not here to do your work for you ;))
Play with it and import it in your Workbook and adjust it where needed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim counter As Integer

'get the last row in this sheet (column A)
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'get the last row in the sheet "Tabelle2" (column A)
With Sheets("Tabelle2")
LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'the counter is needed to add dynamically to "Tabelle2"
counter = LastRow2 + 1
'run from 1 to the last row in your first sheet
For i = 1 To LastRow
    'search for matches
    If Cells(i, 2).Text = "y" Then
        'if found, write to "Tabelle2"
        Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(counter, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, -1).Value
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```